# JS to return a single file type for a variety of similar files (e.g. 'mp4' || 'm4v' = 'MOV')

Tags: javascript, json

I have a populateTable function, and I'm trying to combine a couple of different file types that might be read from the JSON file into one display type. In this case mp4 and m4v into MOV — I'm not getting any errors, but everything is turning up undefined in the table.

```
function populateTable() {
    
    function setGenericType(type) {
        if(type == 'mp4' || type == 'm4v')  {
            return 'MOV'
        }
    }

    for (const d of data) {
        $("#contents").append(`<tr>
            <td>${d.title}</td>
            <td>${d.year}</td>
            <td>${setGenericType(d)}</td>
          </tr>`)   
    }
}
```

Any ideas? An example of the JSON from data.js:

```
{
    "title":"Arc Transition",
    "year":2016,
    "type":"mp4"
}
```

Comment: `d` is not a string, as infered by `d.title` and `d.year`

Comment: You need to pass in `d.type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the whole data object into your `setGenericType` function, but compare the parameter to strings, so they will never match. And if there's no match of type, the function returns `undefined`.

So either treat the parameter of your function as the object you are passing to it

```
function setGenericType(d) {
  if(d.type == 'mp4' || d.type == 'm4v')  {
    return 'MOV'
  }
}
```

Or just pass the type of the object to your function and keep the function as it is

```
for (const d of data) {
  $("#contents").append(`<tr>
    <td>${d.title}</td>
    <td>${d.year}</td>
    <td>${setGenericType(d.type)}</td>
   </tr>`)   
}
```

Comment: Got it -- much appreciated!